# Material-UI Popover component does trigger onClose event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material-ui Popover component, the open of Popover component is handled by its state, I defined a function named handlePopoverClose to handle When I click outside the 'Hover with a Popover', it was supposed to set the state of anchorEl to null, and then state of open should turn to false. But this function action didn't trigger, does anyone know what happen?

```
import React from 'react';
import Popover from '@material-ui/core/Popover';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  popover: {
    pointerEvents: 'none',
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(1),
  },
}));

export default function MouseOverPopover() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const handlePopoverOpen = event => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handlePopoverClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

  return (
    <div>
      <Typography
        aria-owns={open ? 'mouse-over-popover' : undefined}
        aria-haspopup="true"
        onMouseEnter={handlePopoverOpen}
      >
        Hover with a Popover.
      </Typography>
      <Popover
        id="mouse-over-popover"
        className={classes.popover}
        classes={{
          paper: classes.paper,
        }}
        open={open}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: 'bottom',
          horizontal: 'left',
        }}
        transformOrigin={{
          vertical: 'top',
          horizontal: 'left',
        }}
        onClose={handlePopoverClose}
        disableRestoreFocus
      >
        <Typography>I use Popover.</Typography>
      </Popover>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just have to remove below code from your styles:

```
popover: {
    pointerEvents: 'none',
  }
```

It will start working fine. Live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-snow-k6x1d